why do i get this ValueError: No API key found for OpenAI
I'm using llama-index with the following code:
import boto3
from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex

def retrieve_pdf_files_from_s3(bucket_name):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='****',aws_secret_access_key='****',region_name="****")
    response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
    pdf_files = []
    if 'Contents' in response:
        for obj in response['Contents']:
            if obj['Key'].endswith('.pdf'):
                pdf_files.append(obj['Key'])
    return pdf_files


bucket_name = "****"
pdf_files = retrieve_pdf_files_from_s3(bucket_name)
"""
for pdf_data in pdf_files:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='****',aws_secret_access_key='****',region_name="****")
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, pdf_data, './tmp/' + pdf_data)
"""

reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="./tmp")
documents = reader.load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
print(index)
    

Which is a very simple example.
I got the following error when executing it:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\embeddings\utils.py", line 59, in resolve_embed_model
    validate_openai_api_key(embed_model.api_key)
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\embeddings\openai\utils.py", line 104, in validate_openai_api_key   
    raise ValueError(MISSING_API_KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE)
ValueError: No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\app.py", line 25, in <module>
    index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\base.py", line 145, in from_documents
    return cls(
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\indices\vector_store\base.py", line 71, in __init__
    else embed_model_from_settings_or_context(Settings, service_context)
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\settings.py", line 274, in embed_model_from_settings_or_context
    return settings.embed_model
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\settings.py", line 67, in embed_model
    self._embed_model = resolve_embed_model("default")
  File "D:\NusreGrowth\RAG for Own Data\venv\lib\site-packages\llama_index\core\embeddings\utils.py", line 66, in resolve_embed_model
    raise ValueError(
ValueError:
******
Could not load OpenAI embedding model. If you intended to use OpenAI, please check your OPENAI_API_KEY.
Original error:
No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

Consider using embed_model='local'.
Visit our documentation for more embedding options: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/models/embeddings.html#modules
******

There seems to be an error with the code I wrote above. It shows that there is no API key found for OpenAI and it asks me to use an environment variable or some other way to set the API
And in the second execption, the same issue can be seen.
How do I fix this?

Did you set/configure an API key as the error suggest you didn't?

For others who are getting this error when their project shouldn't be using openai... time to switch libraries...
https://github.com/run-llama/llama_index/issues/852

You need to add your OPENAI_API_KEY as suggested by the error.
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

If you are on a hosted environment (e.g. AWS, GCP, etc.), you should have a way to add the variable to your secrets.
If are in your local environment, you can use something like python-dotenv to create a local .env file and include your API key in a safe way.

The error you had is a ValueError based on your API key is Not Found at line 66 of your code via looking carefully at the traceback call. In Python, a ValueError occurs when a function receives an argument of the correct type but with an inappropriate value. It’s raised when the situation isn’t described by a more precise exception, such as IndexError.
You can easily resolve this issue by ensuring that your API key is correctly imported as a string at where you want to use it. You can create .env file in your project root directory and ensure that your OPEN_API key is correctly created before using the key.
Don't forget to wrap your code where this error probably occurs in a try-except block so that you can easily catch the error and resolve it quickly. Here is how using your code snippet as an example:
   

    try:
        bucket_name = "****"
        pdf_files = retrieve_pdf_files_from_s3(bucket_name)
        """
        for pdf_data in pdf_files:
            s3 = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id='****',aws_secret_access_key='****',region_name="****")
            s3.download_file(bucket_name, pdf_data, './tmp/' + pdf_data)
        """

        reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="./tmp")
        documents = reader.load_data()
        index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e) # you can still return e - perhaps with added explanatory f-string.



Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

I don't use ChatGPT whatsoever as a developer. I have been using Python professionally since 2019, and I hate to use a machine that has the potential to make mistakes to answer someone's question. Whatever, I write here, on Stack Overflow, be it questions or answers, I created it by myself to help the community.
